# AWS - How to monitor error codes in aws app

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a nodejs app running in AWS ECS behind an ALB.
I have a requirement where I have to listen http codes mostly 502, 503 and 504 returning from my app if and only if its occurring continuously for a certain period of time (Ex: 504 continuously for the past 10mins) and should be integrated to Slack to see and to act on.

Which Service I should prefer: AWS Cloudwatch Alarms or AWS EventBridge? Any other AWS service that I have to integrate while picking any of the above? Any example or sample reference would be helpful?